# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 ERROR?

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, dart

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1Greetings to everyone I am New among you flutter I want to learn, but I get such an error 5 hours in the solution could not reach it how can we solve? there is such a thing previously?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project ‘android’.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ‘:classpath’.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
Required by:
project :

Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
Could not get resource ‘https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom’.
Could not GET ‘https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom’.
dl.google.com

Try:
Run with –stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with –info or –debug option to get more log output. Run with –scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 6s

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a Flutter issue (I could be wrong), but rather a Gradle one. The error entails that the Gradle plugin dependency failed, when tried to build the project.

I would suggest to look into what Gradle version you are using to build your project and see the compatible version of Gradle Plugin for that.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Refer to this guide to see which Gradle Version is compatible with which Gradle plugin version.  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: Check your Gradle.wrapper and see what version it is installing.

Comment: That's what he says?
"
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
"

Comment: Your project is using 5.6.2 version but flutter is looking for 3.5.0. I dont think i will be of much help as I am not a flutter expert. Wait until someone from that domain answers i guess.